# What do I need to change to get rid of this syntax error that seems to jump from line to line?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I've written a program for a class and I am getting a syntax error that makes no sense on this portion:

"""Output Area"""

#self.outputArea

self.outputArea = self.addTextArea("", row = 3, column = 0)

The syntax error is on the """Output Area""" line, but when I delete that portion, the syntax moves to the "#self.outputArea" line. Then if I delete that line, the syntax error will move down to the "self.outputArea = self.addTextArea". Then down to the function below this line. This is the only error in the entire code and it just seems to keep jumping around.

I'm incredibly confused as I am new to programming. Am I just overlooking something?

Comment: Look at the line that comes *before* the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common siutation. The issue most likely lies in the block before `"""Output Area"""`.

The exact issue is difficult to guess. Some of the common ones off the top of my head are:

1. Incorrect indentation (correct setup of an editor is important here.)
2. Trailing comma
3. Incorrect implementation of exception handling.

The list goes on. As I said, it's difficult to surmise.

Comment: That was it. I forgot a parenthesis at the end of the line above """Output Area""". Thanks to you both.